# On the sharpness of the Harada-Sai lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-algebra, where $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraically closed field. The following result is a well known (see for example *Assem & Coelho - Basic representation theory of algebras*):

> **Lemma (Harada-Sai).** Let $m>0$ and
> $$M_1\xrightarrow[]{f_1} M_2\xrightarrow[]{f_2} \dots \xrightarrow[]{f_{2^m-1}} M_{2^m}$$
> be a radical path where each $M_i$ has composition length at most equal to $m$. Then, $f_{2^m-1}\dots f_2 f_1=0$.

Another well known result is that this bound on the length of non-zero radical paths is a sharp bound (see exercise VI.1.2 of Assem & Coelho).

---

My question is the following : Is the bound given by Harada-Sai's lemma sharp when we restrict ourselves to representation finite algebras? The exercise pointed out above gives an example of the sharpness for the algebra $\mathbb{K}[t_1,t_2]/\langle t_1^2,t_2^2\rangle$ which is representation infinite.

More precisely, I am looking for an example of a representation finite algebra $A$ such that the composition of $2^{m}-2$ radical morphisms (from modules which the lengths are bound by $m$) is non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bongartz gives an example, for any $m$, in Section A.1 on page 326 of

*Bongartz, Klaus*, [**Treue einfach zusammenhaengende Algebren. I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-43888), Comment. Math. Helv. 57, 282-330 (1982). [ZBL0502.16022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0502.16022).

The algebra is given by the quiver
$$
1
\begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow{a}\\
\xleftarrow[b]\\
\end{array}
2
\begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow{a}\\
\xleftarrow[b]\\
\end{array}
3
\cdots
m-1
\begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow{a}\\
\xleftarrow[b]\\
\end{array}
m
$$
with relations $ab=ba=0$.

As an example I'll list the modules in a chain of $14$ morphisms for $m=4$. Arrows to the right indicate the action of $a$; arrows to the left indicate the action of $b$.

$$1\to 2\to3\to4$$
$$1\to2\to3$$
$$1\to2\to3\leftarrow4$$
$$1\to2$$
$$1\to2\leftarrow3\to4$$
$$1\to2\leftarrow3$$
$$1\to2\leftarrow3\leftarrow4$$
$$1$$
$$1\leftarrow2\to3\to4$$
$$1\leftarrow2\to3$$
$$1\leftarrow2\to3\leftarrow4$$
$$1\leftarrow2$$
$$1\leftarrow2\leftarrow3\to4$$
$$1\leftarrow2\leftarrow3$$
$$1\leftarrow2\leftarrow3\leftarrow4$$